# Using no animation segue crashes app

Tags: ios

I am using a `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass to suppress the push animations segue.

```
#import "NoAnimationSegue.h"

@implementation NoAnimationSegue

- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    NSLog(@"src %@", src);
    [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
}

@end
```

Using this segue makes my app crash sometimes in certain situations. When i disable this code and use a push segue instead, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the App Crash message? Also, did you check whether your app consumes too much memory ?

Comment: Didn't you alloc the UIViewController??

Comment: src.navigationController to self.navigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because i had added a gesture recognizer in story board to my  `destinationViewController`.

When i removed the gesture recognizer or added the recognizer through code...it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine for me. How do you call "perform" method in this subclassed segue? I checked your subclass with the following example and it is working fine, Can you please code you are using to call "perform" method?

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
NoAnimationSegue *animate = [[NoAnimationSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"1" source:self destination:second];
[animate perform];
```